# Android licenses is toggling between not found and not accepted

Tags: android, flutter, sdk

Im starting with flutter. I have the flutter sdk setup. When I run `flutter doctor` sometimes it shows 
Android Licenses are not accepted and other times it shows Android licenses are not accepted. Can someone tell me why flutter is gaving this weird behavior.

[image]

Another thing is when I run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` it wont wait for my to input `y`, otherwise it doestn't show anything

[image]

I have 
- Sdk 29,28,27,26 platform
- Obsolete Sdk tool package
- Commandline tools
- emulator
- sdk platform tools

I think it should work with the obsolete sdk tools.
But I have no idea why it is acting weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked when I **reset my windows**.
Its not a perfect solution but hope it will help someone.

Answer (score 1):

I think reinstalling Android Studio after clearning its cache and all other files will help